# Why am I getting Typeerror: 'int' object not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a short program to take ten numbers and reprint them as a list but replacing those below a certain amount with zero. First, 'input' isn't working and prompting me to give the numbers. Second I'm getting 'TypeError: 'int' object not iterable' for the second 'for' loop in the main function. Any ideas?

```
amx = []

def validamount(amount, limit):
    if amount >= limit:
        return amount
    else:
        return 0

def main():
    for i in 10:
        amx.append(int(input()))
    for i in 10:
        print(validamount(amx[i], 5))

main()
```

Comment: `for i in` is used to loop through elements of a collection, like a list or dictionary. `10` isn't a collection, what are you looping through?

Comment: The number `10` is not a list, it's just a number.  You cannot iterate over it.  I'm guessing you want `range(10)`.

Comment: Okay - range(10). Now it works perfectly. Haven't coded for a good few months, stupid mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot iterate over a number, try:

```
for i in range(10):
```

refer to:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Answer (score 2):

`for i in 10:` is the source of your error; it should be `for i in range(10):` instead.